# only keep digits after ":" in regular expression in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to extract the numbers for each parameter below:

```
import re

parameters = '''
             NO2: 42602
             SO2: 42401
             CO: 42101
             '''
```

The desired output should be:`['42602','42401','42101']`

I first tried `re.findall(r'\d+',parameters)`, but it also returns the "2" from "NO2" and "SO2".

Then I tried `re.findall(':.*',parameters)`, but it returns `[': 42602', ': 42401', ': 42101']`

If I can not rename the "NO2" to "Nitrogen dioxide", is there a way just to collect numbers on the right (after ":")?
Many thanks.

Comment: `print(re.findall(r':\s(\d+)',parameters))` - research catpuring groups to only get whats in the group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use capturing groups, you could use look behind.

```
(?<=:\s)\d+
```

**Details**:

- `(?<=:\s)`: gets string after `:\s`
- `\d+`: gets digits

I also tried result on python.

```
import re
parameters = '''
             NO2: 42602
             SO2: 42401
             CO: 42101
             '''

result = re.findall(r'(?<=:\s)\d+',parameters)
print (result)
```

Result

```
['42602', '42401', '42101']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'(?<=:\s)\d+', parameters)
```

Should work. You can learn more about `look-behind` from [here](https://coderwall.com/p/5c7kjq/lookahead-and-lookbehind-regex).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to capture the numbers

```regex
^\s*\w+:\s(\d+)$
```

Hereby, `^` in the beginning asserts the position at the start of the line. `\s*` means that there may be 0 or more whitespaces before the content. `\w+:\s` matches a word character followed by ":" and space, that is "NO2: ".
Finally, `(\d+)` matches the following digits you want as a group. `$` matches the end of the line.

To get all the matches as a list you can use

```py
matches = re.findall(r'^\s*\w+:\s(\d+)$', parameters, re.MULTILINE)
```

As `re.MULTILINE` is specified,

> the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of the string and
> at the beginning of each line.

as stated in the docs.

The result is as follows

```
>> print(matches)
['42602', '42401', '42101']
```

Answer (score 0):

To put my two cents in, you could simpley use

```
re.findall(r'(\b\d+\b)', parameters)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ivEdkp/1).

---

If you happen to have other digits floating around somewhere in your string, be more precise with

```
\w+:\s*(\d+)
```

See [**another demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ivEdkp/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify where in your string do you want to search for digits, you can use:

```
re.findall(r': (\d+)', parameters)
```

This tells Python to look for digits in the part of the string after ":" and the "space".